# How to divide a string in parts to use in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a column in a dataframe like this:

```
   description
link Miami portforward 155 gb
Link Berlin main  10 mbps
link Mexico sub-rout 1 mb
```

I want as output:

```
description                value      unit
link Miami portforward      155        gb
Link Berlin main            10         mbps
link Mexico sub-rout         1         mb
```

i tried something like `[x for x in column if x isdigit()]` but this is a complete fail.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are the last 2 words always the ones to be moved to subsequent columns? Perhaps start from right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using rsplit and limit the split to 2

```
df['description'].str.rsplit(' ', 2,expand=True)
```

```
    0   1   2
1   link Miami portforward  155     gb
2   Link Berlin main    10  mbps
3   link Mexico sub-rout    1   mb
```

OR

alternately, using regex

```
df[['col1','col2']]=df['description'].str.extract(r'(\d+)\s(.*)')
df
```

```
    description     col1    col2
1   link Miami portforward 155 gb   155     gb
2   Link Berlin main 10 mbps    10  mbps
3   link Mexico sub-rout 1 mb   1   mb
```